# Is there an equivalent to javascipt's console.log() in Shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to log some messages to the javascript console from a Shiny application as an alternative to writing to the server-side logs. Shiny does this when an error gets thrown in the application. Is there a generic way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me when I put it in server.R:

```
cat("Hello world!\n", file = stderr())
```